# Distribute records in SQL based on count

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to distribute records equally into two categories. But in case I fall short of records in any one category, I should accommodate count the remaining records in other category.

Sample data:

[image]

If like this students of subject s1 are 12, and subject s2 are 20. I need to pick 30 students, result should give me 15 for each subject, but as s1 total is only 12, I should get 12 from s1 and 18 from s2.

Comment: Question is unclear! Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: edit done, please check and revert

Comment: Can u please upvote the quetion. I have edited it and provided  a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ID INT, Student VARCHAR(10), Subject CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'Stud1', 's1'),
(2, 'Stud2', 's1'),
(3, 'Stud3', 's2'),
(4, 'Stud4', 's2'),
(5, 'Stud5', 's2'),
(6, 'Stud6', 's2'),
(7, 'Stud7', 's2'),
(8, 'Stud8', 's2'),
(9, 'Stud9', 's2')


;WITH cte AS(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY ID) AS rn FROM @t)
SELECT TOP 7 * 
FROM cte
ORDER BY rn, Subject
```

The idea is that you are numbering the rows within subjects like:

```
1   Stud1   s1  1
3   Stud3   s2  1
2   Stud2   s1  2
4   Stud4   s2  2
5   Stud5   s2  3
6   Stud6   s2  4
7   Stud7   s2  5
8   Stud8   s2  6
9   Stud9   s2  7
```

So, when selecting `top N` rows, they are distributing automatically because of ordering by that column.

Comment: Hi Giorgi, Thanks for the solution. This works perfect. Now I have a further requirement of fetching these records evenly based on another column. For example, I have a department column... so under each subject again, I should fetch the records equally from each department. Can you please help in modifying the query further. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @HappieFeet, no I can not...You can ask another question.

Comment: NP. Thanks anyways, this helps a lot.